# Взаимодействие с календарем

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, golang

В программе (на golang) необходимо привязать календарь или что-то вроде этого.
В итоге программа должна уметь отслеживать сколько дней с указанной (известной) даты до определенного дня.
То есть на пример указанная дата 5 мая, и нужно узнать сколько дней до 1 июня.

Что использовать, что гуглить?)

Comment: Начните хотя бы с https://golang.org/pkg/time/.

Comment: для вашего примера https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь:

```
func Since(t Time) Duration
```

Функция [`Since`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) возвращает время прошедшее с `t`.
Это сокращение для `time.Now().Sub(t)`.