# Golang time database

Tags: база-данных, golang, время

Люди добрые помогите, пожалуйста, не знающему человеку.

В программе (на golang) необходимо привязать календарь. 
В итоге программа должна уметь отслеживать сколько дней с указанной (известной) даты до определенного дня. 
То есть на пример указанная дата 5 мая, и нужно узнать сколько дней до 1 июня.

Что использовать, что гуглить?)

Перерыл много ресурсов но ничего не нашел, плохо искал наверное(
Как я понял в go в данном случае нужно использовать библиотеку time но поней тоже ничего не нашел.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос многократно.

Answer (score 1):

Вся мудрость здесь: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date

Пример https://play.golang.org/p/itLuNA5vVP

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1 := time.Date(2017, time.May, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    t2 := time.Date(2017, time.June, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

    diff := t2.Sub(t1)

    fmt.Printf("diff type: %T, value: %v, days: %v \n", diff, diff, diff.Hours()/24.0)

}
```

[Наглый плагиат от сюда :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839043/678491)

@user275190 пожалуйста читайте комментарии к вашим вопросам, на ваш [первый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748272/218692) уже отвечали

Гуглить это: [golang time difference](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=golang+time+difference)